# SSRS Link to Open In New Window

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, hyperlink

How can I get a link to open in a new window with an IIF function combined with a field:

```
=iif(  Fields!StrippedABC.Value<>"", "https://intranet.mysite.com/...samplesample" & Fields!StrippedABC.Value & "&Source=https%3A%2FajlkjakfjC084F64168657E&RootFolder=%2Fquality%2FLists%2FABC", "https://intranet.mysite.com/quality/Lists/differentlink.aspx")
```

I have tried various methods of using javascript:void(window.open  as well as the _blank method and I can't seem to get the appropriate syntax for these links to open in a new window from the SSRS server.

What is the correct syntax in the above example for the links to open in a new window?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the _blank method inside of an HTML tag, then render the text box as HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the JavaScript window open method.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('https://intranet.mysite.com/...','_blank'))"
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer was helpful and helped me arrive at the solution:

=iif(Fields!MyVariable.Value<>"", 
"javascript:void(window.open('https://intranet...."
& Fields!MyVariable.Value &  "&moreurlstuffhere_blank'))" ,
"javascript:void(window.open('https://intranet....','_blank'))")

Which works very well as a solution.